# how do I place a <div> inside another <div> so that the background goes flush to the sides and my text is contained

Tags: css

I want to nest a div inside another div so that the outer div grows with the inner div as the inner div has text placed inside it. Would appreciate any help. [Here is a link](http://www.hnw7.com) so you get the idea. You will need to open your browser up to full screen to see the bottom of it correctly.

Hello Slalvenko, Have posted up both your code (thank you kindly) and my code which I know is not perfect but I'm learning.  Yes I am aware of css reset styles that set browser default values to 0 and I did download one once.  But I'm hoping that in a years time I will be aware of all of this and just write it into my code.  I suppose a reset saves time and trouble but I'm enjoying pottering around what with all of this being new to me.  Here is your code and my code.  Mine is slightly different because I was wanting to add two more divs to it later which I will show you when I get there.  Mike  http://www.hnw7.com

Comment: I do not really get what you want, but maybe you're looking for display: inline-block

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer {

    background-color: #CCF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;       
}

.inner {
    width: 535px;
    background-color: #E6E6FF;
    color: black;        
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm not sure if this was your question but try this. The floats in your .inner div are making the parent's height 0, since the floats take those elements from the document flow. You need to clear those floats if you want your parent to have actual height. I find that easiest way to do so is to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent element.

You can read about clearing floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

Comment: thank you so much Slavenko,  You are the first person to respond to my second question, so this is a land mark for me.  Before I saw your post I had been trying for hours to do this and this is what I finished up with?  http://www.hnw7.com/box_within_box.html  I don't know if I will have trouble down the line with this because I don't fully understand what a float is???  It took me all day to figure out how to do what I have just done?  How do you find out that I asked a question in the first place???  This site is so confusing I don't know where I am half the time :-( Mike.  But thank you !!!

Comment: Hi Slavenko,  I tried your example and it works the only thing I was trying to figure out is how to get the white border around it to go away so that I have only the coloured background going right to the edges of the screen.  Can you show me how to achieve that because I would really like to use the code you have sent me.  Will I still have to do something with the float thing what ever that is????  Thank you in advance.  Your input has been very useful to me. Are you programming in Python as well?  I did want to know more about that but I have bugged you enough already.  Thank you.  Mike

Comment: @MichaelEdwin To remove white border add this to your CSS code `body {margin:0;}`. Every browser has some default styling (in your case the body tag has a default margin of 10px) so it's a common practice to add CSS reset styles that set those browser default values to 0;

Comment: There is not enough room for me to try and explain floats to you in this little comments box, but you should not be trying to seriously code HTML without understanding how floats work. [This](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) is a good place to start

Comment: In a nutshell, think of a pull-quote in a magazine article - it is "floated" so the article text wraps around it. However, because it is taken out the main document flow, it is not included in the calculation of its parent element's height. @Slavenko's comment about `overflow: hidden` is a handy - but convoluded - shortcut to trigger the parent element to include floated content in its dimensional layout.